# What is the most efficient way to take data from one workbook and add to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to take data from one workbook and add it to another workbook in the most efficient way possible. I've tried copy and paste values which was the least efficient method I tried at ~maybe 5 minutes. I am currently using .value2 = value2. Using this the total time it takes to open a 35,000 KB workbook and copy it over to another and then close the 35,000 KB workbook is roughly 99 seconds. I'd like speed this up to less a minute, but obviously the quicker the better. Here is the code I am using -

```
Lastrow = fromWs.Range("A" & fromWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

toWs.Range("A2:CQ" & Lastrow - 13).Value2 = fromWs.Range("A15:CQ" & Lastrow).Value2
```

Any ideas on how to speed this up substantially? I already have ScreenUpdating = False, Calculation set to xlCalculation Manual, etc. Thanks!

Comment: How long does it take to open the file?

Comment: Is there data all the way to column `"CQ"` ?  If not, maybe a more dynamic way of finding the edge of the data would speed things up.  Small tricks like turning off screen updating (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`) can improve speed too.  Just make sure to turn it back on when your process completes or if it hits any errors.

Comment: It takes ~20-25 seconds to open the file and closer to ~50-75 seconds to use the .value = .value.

Comment: There is data all the way to CQ. The report I am adding is defined/set so there will always be data to CQ.

Comment: Did you try opening the file `ReadOnly` and `UpdateLinks=False`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx

Comment: i will test this. thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, opening the file ReadOnly and UpdateLinks=False did not improve performance. Actually, slowed performance from 99 seconds to 103 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A 35 mb workbook is very large....

### Here is something you can practice with:

You can create formulas to reference a closed workbook with VBA.

For this example I have a workbook saved as

### "C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\Closed_WB.xlsx"

In order to find the last row in the closed workbook I would use this formula.

```
=MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307, 'C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\[Closed_WB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,TRUE)
```

I have put this formula in Z1 using VBA

### This formula only finds numbers, use a different one to find text

```
 With sh

        Set rng = .Range("Z1")
        rng = "=MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307, 'C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\[Closed_WB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,TRUE)"
```

So now Z1 indicates the last row of the closed workbook.

I now place the reference formula in `range("A2:CQ2")`

```
  LstRw = .Range("Z1") - 10
        Set FrmLA_Rng = .Range("A2:CQ" & LstRw)
        .Range("A2:CQ2") = "='C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\[Closed_WB.xlsx]Sheet1'!R[10]C"
```

Use `autofill` to fill down the formulas to the last row.

```
 .Range("A2:CQ2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:CQ" & LstRw), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Then turn those formulas into values

```
FrmLA_Rng.Value = FrmLA_Rng.Value
```

The complete code looks like this:

```
Sub Get_Row()
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Integer, FrmLA_Rng As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With sh

        Set rng = .Range("Z1")
        rng = "=MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307, 'C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\[Closed_WB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A,TRUE)"
        LstRw = .Range("Z1") - 10
        Set FrmLA_Rng = .Range("A2:CQ" & LstRw)
        .Range("A2:CQ2") = "='C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\[Closed_WB.xlsx]Sheet1'!R[10]C"
        .Range("A2:CQ2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:CQ" & LstRw), Type:=xlFillDefault
        FrmLA_Rng.Value = FrmLA_Rng.Value

    End With

End Sub
```

There is also an option of using this formula, (if you have no blanks in column A)

```
 "=COUNTA( 'C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\[Closed_WB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A)"
```

Comment: Seems cool. I will try this. How much do you think this will improve performance?

Comment: I don't know...I just tested it on a small scale, let us know.